# If $f$ is one-to-one, does the image of the complement equal the complement of the image?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

So, I can't figure out if the following statement is true or not:

For a function $f:X \rightarrow Y$, if $f$ is one-to-one, then $f(A^C)=(f(A))^C$ where $B \subset X$.

I have an example below which suggests that this is not always true.  However, I've recently had several people (without proof) tell me that it is true.  So I honestly don't know.  Observe my example below:

Define $f:X\rightarrow Y$ where $X=\lbrace 1, 2 \rbrace$, $Y=\lbrace 1, 2, 3 \rbrace$, in such a way that $f(\lbrace 1 \rbrace) = \lbrace 1 \rbrace$ and $f(\lbrace 2 \rbrace) = \lbrace 2 \rbrace$.  Let $A\subset X$.  Now let $A=\lbrace 1 \rbrace\rightarrow f(A)=\lbrace 1 \rbrace$.  So that means that $A^C=\lbrace 2 \rbrace \rightarrow f(A^C)= \lbrace 2 \rbrace$.  Yet $(f(A))^C= \lbrace 2, 3 \rbrace$.

This seems to disprove the statement... right?  Or is there something fundamental about complementation that I'm not understanding here?

Answer (score 4):

You're right. For injective functions, the image of the complement is only guaranteed to be a *subset* of the complement of the image, and the example you've given proves that.

If $f$ is *surjective* as well as injective, however, then the image of the complement and the complement of the image are the same (this is a good exercise).